# iText: add images with projective transform

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'm trying to add an image to a PDF using iText. This image must be included with a projective transformation. I was able to find a way to include images with affine transformation but I couldn't find a way to add images that require projective transformation, such as the following example:

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9qZE.png) => [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWxGH.png)

Does anyone know if it is possible to do that and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible to do using the transformation capabilities of the PDF format. As you already found out there are are mechanisms to do affine transforms but that as far as it goes. You'll have to process the images before including them in the PDF.